# Pointing to files on my server

Tags: javascript, file, directory, webserver

I'm having some difficulty pointing to one of my JS files on my server. I have a pretty standard set up:

- index.html
- js folder
- css folder

The difficulty is I have another folder called

- 6_toggle

Within this folder I have six HTML files named `1.html`, `2.html`, etc. I need these individual files to point to a file in my JS folder. I thought it would be:

```
<script src="../../js/view.min.js?auto"></script>
```

I've also tried:

```
<script src="../js/view.min.js?auto"></script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Would anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: is your 6_toggle in the same folder as your other three folders?

Comment: also, why are there '?'s in your file extensions? Do you have some wonky .htaccess setup?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tree structure looks like this:

```
-index.html
-js_folder
-css_folder
-6_toggle
  -1.html
  -2.html
  -etc
```

from index, you first need to reach into the js folder, then the file.js like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_folder/file.js"></script>
```

from within your 1.html and 2.html files, you'd access the file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js_folder/file.js"></script>
```

You must first reach into the parent folder, then down into the js folder for its children

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding. I've tried that but still nothing. Here's a link to the site if it's any use. The 6_toggle folder is for the gallery section. http://orchidaberdeen.com/

Comment: @Cameron is your js file working from any page? or just not particular pages?

Comment: two possible solutions: remove the "?auto" portion of the file name. Also you might try writing a function into the js file like: function tester(){alert('source found')}; then call that function in the html to ensure that you are really not reading the source, or that it's not doing what you think it should

Comment: I've tried to implement as you suggested but still struggling. Can't seem to get call the function through the html.

Comment: add a new javascript file to the same directory as the troublesome file. Create that function from before, namely: function test(){alert('source found');} then call this function from the html page to see if you can even access the new file.

Comment: think i've figured out the problem just don't know how to fix it. The jQuery doesn't appear to be triggering on the single html files.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this structure

```
 root/
    -index.html
    -js_folder
    -css_folder
    -6_toggle
      -1.html
      -2.html
      -etc
```

You can access `js_folder` any time with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js_folder/file.js"></script>` <- I think this is a best practice for accessing file asset on server. By include root, you can fotget how many `..` needed to go back

Comment: This is the latest.

It works perfectly [here](http://orchidaberdeen.com/6_toggle/1.html),

But once it get's pulled into the [index.html](http://orchidaberdeen.com/)  it doesn't want to work.

So strange and i'm officially out of ideas...

Comment: What do you mean "pulled"? I think you should try to change all link to begin of root ("/"). It's will work. Eg `/index.html, /js_folder/js.js, /6_toggle/1.html`

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I tried that earlier but it unfortunately didn't work, i've also tried absolute links. But it just give me the same results - It appears to be working in it's own file (1.html, 2.html, etc) http://orchidaberdeen.com/6_toggle/1.html but as soon as it gets pulled into the index.html it doesn't want to work. http://orchidaberdeen.com/#gallery

Comment: How do you know that the link did not work or your code has some error in it? Try to debug with firebut (net module) or inspect element

Comment: I'm not getting any errors relating to the script or the html files within the 6_toggle folder. The jQuery from 1.html doesn't seem to be getting pulled through into index.html. Even with absolute links.

Comment: OK, when ever you call jquery script, you must ensure that jquery has been load successfully by wrap your code with $(function(){//Code here}) or $(document).load...

Comment: Thank you but as far as i'm aware i have got the script wrapped with $(function) or $(document)

I'm beginning to wonder if it's got something to do with the fact that i'm using jQuery to pull through another piece of jQuery?